# How to do the time series prediction using LSTM for images?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, scikit-learn, spyder

1. I have 20 images for different time period
2. After reading them as an array I have about 100000 pixels whose values are known for 20 time period and I have to predict the 21st time period value for each pixel using LSTM.
3. I am training my model by using the X_train that have 5 time values as input and Y_train takes 6th time value.
4. The output I want is something like Y=[260]  if I gave X=[500,450,390,350,300]  as an input.
5. I have an array of all images that is of shape (100769,20)

My code is as follows please suggest something.

## Library used

```py
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.backend import clear_session
```

creation of  training data for 5years

```py
for c in range(100769):
    X=[]
    Y=[]
    for d in range (15):
        x=res_arr[c][d:d+5]
        X.append(x)
        y=res_arr[c][d+5]
        Y.append(y)
```

## Keras usage

```py
Initialising the RNN
X_train=(1/6300)*(np.array(X))
X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1],1))
Y=np.reshape(Y,(15,1))
Y_train=(1/6300)*(Y)
```

Initialising the RNN

```py
regressor = Sequential()
```

Adding the first LSTM layer and some Dropout regularisation

```py
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 30, return_sequences = True,activation='relu',input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], 1)))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))
```

Adding a second LSTM layer and some Dropout regularisation

```py
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 30, activation='relu',return_sequences = True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))
```

Adding a third LSTM layer and some Dropout regularisation

```py
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 30,activation='relu', return_sequences = True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))
```

Adding a fourth LSTM layer and some Dropout regularisation

```py
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 30,activation='relu'))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))
```

Adding the output layer

```py
regressor.add(Dense(units = 1,activation='relu'))
```

Compiling the RNN

```py
regressor.compile(optimizer = 'Adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Fitting the RNN to the Training set

```py
regressor.fit(X_train, Y_train)
_, accuracy = regressor.evaluate(X_train, Y_train)
#print('Accuracy: %.2f' % (accuracy*100))
acc.append(accuracy*100)
```

the summary of the model

```py
regressor.summary()
```

```sh
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 5, 30)             3840      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 5, 30)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_2 (LSTM)                (None, 5, 30)             7320      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 5, 30)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_3 (LSTM)                (None, 5, 30)             7320      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 5, 30)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_4 (LSTM)                (None, 30)                7320      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_4 (Dropout)          (None, 30)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 31        
=================================================================
Total params: 25,831
Trainable params: 25,831
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: Could you print the summary ?

Comment: I have attached the summary of the model in the above question.

Answer (score 2):

Change your last layer to

```
regressor.add(Dense(units = 1,activation='linear'))
```